# show a Facebook user profile image from url to image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have a url of image which is fetched by the Facebook profile .I fetch those url and copy in to string "urlpicture" .In url picture my url show but when i pass in "geturl"which is a string type property in another file .when i go in to another file "geturl " is nil.

Thats why i can't show my image on image view.I save image url only in string format .Should i have some thing different to show my image on another view.

```
         - (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
            didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                            error:(NSError *)error
            {
                FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                              parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,name,picture,email,gender"}
                                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    // Insert your code here
                    NSLog(@"%@",result);
                    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
             {    NSDictionary *pictureData  = [result valueForKey:@"picture"];
                        NSDictionary *redata = [pictureData valueForKey:@"data"];
                                _urlpicture = [redata valueForKey:@"url"];

                    }





                }];


                HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

                [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[pushWithSlot] animated:YES];
                pushWithSlot.geturl=_urlpicture;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, actually pass the variable before navigation

```
HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

 pushWithSlot.geturl=_urlpicture;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[pushWithSlot] animated:YES];
```

the above one is not work, try this the reason is the URl is inside in your block

```
{    NSDictionary *pictureData  = [result valueForKey:@"picture"];
                    NSDictionary *redata = [pictureData valueForKey:@"data"];
                            _urlpicture = [redata valueForKey:@"url"];

       // call after URL Fetch
                 HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

 pushWithSlot.geturl=_urlpicture;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[pushWithSlot] animated:YES];
                }
```

then try this

```
  {    NSDictionary *pictureData  = [result valueForKey:@"picture"];
                    NSDictionary *redata = [pictureData valueForKey:@"data"];
                            _urlpicture = [redata valueForKey:@"url"];

       // call after URL Fetch
                 HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

 pushWithSlot.geturl=pushWithSlot;
[self presentViewController:pushWithSlot 
               animated:YES 
             completion:nil];
                }
```

Comment: sir-I get value in my url bt i jump on the same view if i write your second code .It navigate on same view..

Comment: HomeViewController is your another view controller or same view controller

Comment: Home view controller is another view controller and i want to jump those view controller but with out back button

Comment: then use your navigation as present or modal , it does not show the back button bro, check the updated answer bro

Comment: pushWithSlot.geturl=pushWithSlot;       sir i think in the place of push with slot url picture come.if i do this then i jump not view but nil value of geturl .if i do url picture then i get value bt could not jump not view

Comment: yeah sir i get ...Thanks..And you are genius many times you help me ..Thanks a lot..

Comment: no not now sir..But you are really good nature and genius person...I hope you help me in future...Thanks..My skupe is:-hkrajput122.Plz ping

Comment: I am not mostly use skype , this is my number 9790811202 (whatsapp),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94309/discussion-between-harsh-chauhan-and-anbu-karthik).